# How to get the width of a Slide Over or Split View?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to match my view with the width of slide over and split views, but I can't find good resources on how to achieve that, doesn anyone know get the width of a Slide Over or Split View, so that I can change my view to something like:

```
calss myView: UIView {

    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {

        ...

        let horizontalClass = traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass
        if horizontalClass == .compact {
            width = viewWidth - 20
        } else {
            width = 400
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can do what you want by override `public func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)` method instead of `func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)`

Comment: Can you give me a more detailed implementation of this method? Where should I put this function?

Comment: `public func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)` will get called when the view controller's view changes its size. So if you want to get the width of a split view then this is the most appropriate place to get it.

You can get its size by override this method on your master view controller.